# change nans in dataframe of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I read from cvs file. My dataframe contains strings that are really floats. Also there are NaN values. 
Basically I want to transformate NaN in mean and strings in floats. 
 
There are methodes that could help like `fillna` that replaces nan values, for it I cant get mean (cause values are strings). 
Also there is a `float()` methode but if it's applied on NaN it will give 0, that is not good for me. 
Is there any good decision to replace NaN values by mean and convert strings into floats? 
Example of dataframe:

```
1   9,5  50,6  45,75962845  2,6  6,5   11  8,9  NaN  
2  10,5  59,9  74,44538987    0  4,5  8,9  NaN  NaN
3  20,1  37,7          NaN  0,8  2,5  9,7  6,7  4,2  
4  10,7  45,2   10,9710853  0,4  3,1  6,9  5,5  4,7    
5  13,2  39,9   9,23393302    0  5,8  9,2  7,4  4,3
```

P.S As A. Leistra proposed I used

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
    df[col].fillna(df[col].mean())
```

`to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` creates a lot of new NaNs. `errors='ignore'` parameter seems to be good, but gives `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly` on the line `df[col].fillna(df[col].mean())`

P.S.2 As piRSquared advised I tried to add `decimal=','` in read_csv function. But it gives still the same error `TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. For example, give a dataframe with example data and *show us* what you want as output.

Answer (score 3):

You should have read in the data using a `decimal=','` argument if you used `pd.read_csv`.  Otherwise, if you're stuck with this data frame, you can dump it out to a csv and try again.

```
pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)), decimal=',')

   0     1     2          3    4    5     6    7    8
0  1   9.5  50.6  45.759628  2.6  6.5  11.0  8.9  NaN
1  2  10.5  59.9  74.445390  0.0  4.5   8.9  NaN  NaN
2  3  20.1  37.7        NaN  0.8  2.5   9.7  6.7  4.2
3  4  10.7  45.2  10.971085  0.4  3.1   6.9  5.5  4.7
4  5  13.2  39.9   9.233933  0.0  5.8   9.2  7.4  4.3
```

---

Filling in missing data becomes easy.

```
d = pd.read_csv(pd.io.common.StringIO(df.to_csv(index=False)), decimal=',')
d.fillna(d.mean())

   0     1     2          3    4    5     6      7    8
0  1   9.5  50.6  45.759628  2.6  6.5  11.0  8.900  4.4
1  2  10.5  59.9  74.445390  0.0  4.5   8.9  7.125  4.4
2  3  20.1  37.7  35.102509  0.8  2.5   9.7  6.700  4.2
3  4  10.7  45.2  10.971085  0.4  3.1   6.9  5.500  4.7
4  5  13.2  39.9   9.233933  0.0  5.8   9.2  7.400  4.3
```

Comment: That's creative. :)

Comment: thank you, but I dont understand how pd.io.common.StringIO works. Actually I read my data from file cvs

Comment: StringIO treats a string like a file. If you use read_csv then put the argument decimal=“,” in that call

Comment: `decimal=','` doesnt help, there is TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Your question started out as "How to fix this data frame?" and you provided the sample data.  However, if you want to fix the issue at its root, namely in the `read_csv` step, then edit your post and add what the csv looks like.  Copy its contents and paste that into the post.

Comment: Actually there are 2 problems 1) replace NaN values by mean 2) to get mean it should be float values, so convert values in float from string.

Comment: I don't see any csv data in your post.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to convert the strings to floats using `to_numeric`:

```
for col in df.columns:
   df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')
```

(Using 'coerce' replace non-convertible values with NaN, which is what you want here). Then you will be able to use `fillna`:

```
df.fillna(df.mean())
```

Comment: ` pd.to_numeric(df[col], errors='coerce')`  created a lot of new NaNs